# create objects using user input number of object

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am a new user in java. As a programming exercise i have to make a program that - asks how many objects the user wants to create and then creates them. Class also calls for a class method that prints the number of created objects. also 
to write the class which creates the objects. Class must be able to keep track of the number of created objects. Class also needs the method that prints the number of objects. Check the completed class for the names of the class and method.

I have tried following but have not reached any where so i am expecting some help: Please help!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfObjects{
   public static void main(String args[]) {

       System.out.print("How many objects do you want to create:");
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       int amount = reader.nextInt();

       Thing[] things = new Thing[amount];

       for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
           things[i] = new Thing();
       }

       Thing.numberOfObjects();
   }
   class Thing{
       int count;

       public void numberOfObjects(){
           System.out.println(count);

       }


   }
}
```

Comment: Start with a main function, which does everything you want in the right order, then write classes, methods, functions which implement the functionality required by **main()**.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot 3 things:

1- to increment the count of the objects when they are created. You can do so in the Thing constructor.

2- declare the count variable as static to allow the variable to be shared between all objects of type Thing.

3 - to declare the numberOfObjects method as static since it is a class method that you are accessing via the Thing class

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfObjects{
public static void main(String args[]) {

   System.out.print("How many objects do you want to create:");
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   int amount = reader.nextInt();

   Thing[] things = new Thing[amount];

   for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
       things[i] = new Thing();
   }

   Thing.numberOfObjects();
   }
   class Thing{
   private static int count = 0;

   public Thing(){
   count++;
   }
   public static void numberOfObjects(){
       System.out.println(count);

   }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Box
{
   //Keep track of all your objects
   Thing[] objs;
   int cursor;

   public Box(int countOfObjects)
   {
         objs = new Thing[countOfObjects];
   }
   //add new object to the array
   public void add(Thing thing)
   {
       objs[cursor++] = thing
   }
   //gets the object
   public Thing getThing(int pos)
   {
        if(pos < 0 || pos >= objs.lenght())
               throw;

        return objs[pos]; 
   }
   //count the objects
   public int numberOfObjects()
   {
       System.out.println(objs.lenght());
       return objs.lenght(); 
   }

   }
}

class Thing()
{
  //any field you need to store
}
```

Your main should look like this

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

   System.out.print("How many objects do you want to create:");
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   int amount = reader.nextInt();

   Box box = new Box(amount);

   for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
       box.Add(new Thing());
   }

   box.numberOfObjects();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare count as static and add count in constructor.Another import thing,move Thing class out of NumberOfObjects Class,otherwise, the Thing class is an inner class, you will need create NumberOfObjects instance first and use this object to create Thing instance.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfObjects{

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("How many objects do you want to create:");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amount = reader.nextInt();

    Thing[] things = new Thing[amount];
    for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
        things[i] = new Thing();
    }
    Thing.numberOfObjects();
}
```

}

```
class Thing{
    private static int count ;
    public Thing(){
        count++;
    }
    public static void numberOfObjects(){
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```